# data is updated on database but Ajax is not successful

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to update information on database. It is updated when i use this line of codes. Unfortunately it is telling me that my ajax is not successfull since it didnt proceed to success function. please help.

**HTML CODE**

```
<form class="EditEmployees" method="POST">
                                <span>Employee ID:</span><span id="employeeid"></span>
                                        <span>First Name</span>
                                        <input type="text" id="editfirstname" name="editfirstname" placeholder="" class="tb-style">

                                        <span>Last Name</span>
                                        <input type="text" id="editlastname" name="editlastname" placeholder="" class="tb-style">

                                            <span class="label" for="">Gender</span>
                                            <select class="tb-style" name="editgender" id="editgender">
                                                <option>Please Select</option>
                                                <option value = "male">Male</option>
                                                <option value="female">Female</option>
                                            </select>

                                                    <span class="label" for="dob">Date of Birth</span>
                                                    <input type="date" id="editdob" name="editdob" class="tb-style">

                                            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' >
                                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="label" for="dob">Date Hired</span>
                                                    <input type="date" id="editdatehired" name="editdatehired" class="tb-style">

                                <button type="" class="btn-EditSave w-100" name="">Save Changes</button>
                    </form>
```

JQuery code.

```
$('.btn-EditSave').click(function(){
            // alert($('#editfirstname').val())
            $.ajax({
                   url:'ajax.php',
                   data:{id:id,
                        type:'update-records-via-id',
                        FirstName:$('#editfirstname').val(),
                        LastName:$('#editlastname').val(),  
                        dob:$('#editdob').val(),
                        datehired:$('#editdatehired').val(),
                        gender:$('#editgender').val()
                    },
                   dataType:'JSON',
                   type:'POST',
                   success: function(data){
                    alert("data saved")
                   }
                })
        })
```

PHP CODE: update data on database

```
function updaterecordviaid($id,$FirstName,$LastName,$gender,$dob,$datehired,$position){
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
    $result = "update employees set FirstName = '$FirstName', LastName='$LastName', Gender = '$gender', DateOfBirth = '$dob', DateHired= '$datehired', PositionId='$position' where EmployeeId='$id'"; 
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$result)){
        echo json_encode(array('message'=>'Record Succesfully Updated!','FirstName'=>$FirstName,'LastName'=>$LastName));
        return;
    }
        echo json_encode(array('message'=>'Something went wrong'));
        return;
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the code where you call the function?

Comment: Check in your Network tab *(which is located in the dev tools)* to see what the ajax returns. Or try removing `return`

Comment: @CarlBinalla I tried looking on it on network several times but it doesnt return anything.

Comment: @catcon here the codes where i call the function

if($_POST['type'] == 'update-records-via-id'){
 return updaterecordviaid($_POST['id'],
  $_POST['FirstName'],
  $_POST['LastName'],
  $_POST['gender'],
  $_POST['dob'],
  $_POST['datehired']
}

Comment: Try returning just the array in the function, then use `echo json_encode(updaterecordviaid(..., ...))`

Comment: @CarlBinalla still the same scenario. data updated on db but it doesnt proceeds to ajax success function.

Comment: Any error in the console? Add `error: function(status, xhr, error){console.log(error);}`

Comment: where should i add that?

Comment: remove your `return` and use `return json_encode` instead of `echo json_encode` .. and to call your function use `echo updaterecordviaid(......`

Comment: Also `preventDefault()` the default form redirect by use `$('.btn-EditSave').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ....`
`

Comment: It is only a minor error. I just put outside my button submit outside the form and it works perfectly. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Yes that is because you need to `preventDefault()` .. see my previous comment

Comment: Is this all on one page?

Comment: Or make button type=“button” to prevent default submit behavior

Comment: can you please check your request goes succesfully into the php funtion ? echo in frst line of php code and exit, then check in network tab